# How can I scale the SCNPhysicsShape when scaling a SCNNode?

Tags: ios, scenekit

I wrote a script that would match all models to one size, no matter the original size of the source model. So now these models fit precisely in the scene, but unfortunately when I add `SCNPhysicsBody` to them (with `SCNPhysicsShape`), their colliders (shapes) are not scaled. They do not match the current size of a node.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `SCNPhysicsShape` (and physics generally in SceneKit) does not actually respect node scale. It will not use the new scale, instead it will create a SCNPhysicsShape respecting the old scale of node.

But you can force to use the new scale.

Just create a physics body with nil (or null if you are using xamarin ios) for the shape parameter.

E.g.:

```
body = SCNPhysicsBody(node, nil)
```

or for xamarin ios

```
body = SCNPhysicsBody.Create(node, null)
```